# How to pass an array from JavaScript function in jsp page to the controller class?

Tags: javascript, java, spring-mvc

I have implemented a JavaScript button action to push all checked elements in a jsp page into an array. So now I need to pass this array to the controller class.I need to delete elements of that array within the controller function.   How can I do that?The thing I need is just pas 
The JavaScript function, jsp form and controller class functions are as below.

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
function selected(){
 var all_checked = document.querySelectorAll('input[name=checkbox]:checked');
 //document.write(all_checked.length);
 var selectedIds = [];

 for(var x = 0, l = all_checked.length; x < l;  x++)
 {
  selectedIds.push(all_checked[x].value);
     //document.write(all_checked[x].value);
 }
 
 return selectedIds; 
}

</script>

> selectedIds is containing the checked items in the jsp page.
```

```html
<form:form method="post" action="createnewstory/${userstoryId} }" modelAttribute="selectedIds" modelAttribute="fulluserstory">
<div class="container">
<div class="deletebutton">
<input id="deleteAllButton"  onClick="selected()" class="btn-lg btn-primary pull-right" type="submit" name="actionButton" value="Delete Selected"></input>
</div>
<div class="content">
<c:if test="${!empty storyList}">

  <table class="table">
  <thead>
   <tr>
   <th></th>
    <th>User Story Id</th>
    <th>User Story Name</th>
    <th>Status</th>
   </tr>
   </thead>
   
  <tbody>
   <c:forEach items="${storyList}" var="userstory">
   
    <tr>
    <td class="checkbox"><input name="checkbox" type="checkbox" value="${userstory.userstoryId}" id="####" ></td>
    <td class="uId"><c:out value="${userstory.userstoryId}"/></td>
    <td class="uName">
      <a href="<c:url value='/viewuserstory/${userstory.userstoryId}'/>"><c:out value="${userstory.userstoryname}"/></a>
    </td>
    <td class="uStatus"><c:out value="${userstory.status}"/></td> 
     
    </tr>
  </c:forEach>  
  </tbody>
  
  </table>
  </c:if>
  </div>
  </div>
</form:form>
```

```html
@RequestMapping(value="/createnewstory",method=RequestMethod.POST)
 public String createNewStory(Map<String,Object> map,@ModelAttribute("fulluserstory") Fulluserstory fulluserstory,@RequestParam String actionButton,HttpServletRequest request){
  if (actionButton.equals("Delete Selected")){
   int [] checkedlist={73,74};
    for(int i=0;i<checkedlist.length;i++){
     int userstoryId=checkedlist[i];
     userstoryService.delete(userstoryId);
     System.out.println(checkedlist[i]);
     System.out.println("delete#######selected inside for");
    }
       }
```

> I need to get setectedIds array in controller,as checkedlist array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can stringify your array

JSON.stringify(selectedIds);

In controller, accept this as String parameter ,convert it back to array or list based on your requirement.

Thanks,
Ravindra

Answer (score 0):

I'm suggesting you to using primefaces `remote command`. You can  find details in [here](https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/ajax/remoteCommand.xhtml).

Comment: can't I pass the array as a parameter to the controller class??

Comment: thank you for your suggestion. Can you suggest a way to pass the array?

Comment: serialise the array and pass it as string and deserialise it in controller class like @Ravindra Kumar 's answer.

Answer (score -1):

First Way to Do this is
Pass Javascript array variable with form action to get values on Controller.

And get it on controller like this

```
String selectedIds[] = request.getParameterValues("selectedIds");
```

make var `selectedIds = [];` global

Comment: still unable to get your array comment here i will tell you second way

Comment: how can I make var selectedIds = []; global:

Comment: after adding this String selectedIds[] = request.getParameterValues("selectedIds");
It is giving nullpoint exception when I'm accessing selectedIds in controller.That means data hasn't been passed??

Comment: thank you for the reply. still I was unable to solve this.